# How do I slice an array into arrays of different sizes and combine them?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want something as simple as the pseudocode below:

```
ar = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
last = ar.length-1
s = ar[0, 1..3, last] #fake code
puts s
```

Expected output has no 8:
4,5,6,7,9

Error:

```
bs/test.rb:12:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

I know that it can accept only two args. Is there a simple way to get what I need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it, you're just using the wrong method, you should be using [`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) instead of `Array#[]`:

```
ar.values_at(0, 1..3, -1)
# => [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Also note that in Ruby, indices "wrap around", so that `-1` is always the last element, `-2` is second-to-last and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any ways to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean? This answer shows you how to do it.

Comment: Yes, it works. I was wondering if you have any other methods also. This one is good enough though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way also -

```
ar = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
arr = []
arr << ar[0..0]   #arr[0] will return a single value but ar[0..0] will return it in array.
arr << ar[1..3]
arr << ar[-1..-1]
```

on printing `arr` it will give following output -

```
[[4], [5, 6, 7], [9]]
```